# How to pass a Class constructor or Type as a parameter

Tags: c#

I am looking to dynamically construct an object from it's type or constructor.

```
var typeList = new List<Type>();
typeList.Add(String); // Error: 'string' is a type, which is not valid in this context
typeList.Add(CustomObject); // Error: 'CustomObject' is a type, which is not valid in this context
```

Because I want to do something among the lines of

```
// Pseudo code
foreach(var t in typeList){
  var obj = new t();
}
```

Comment: Use typeof(string)

Comment: `string str = (string)System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(string));`

Comment: @RandRandom is there a different declaration I could use for the T of List that would allow me to pass the Class names in without typeof?

Comment: You can also have a `List<Func<object>>()`, then `list.Add(() => new object())`, `list.Add((() => new string())`, then `foreach (var t in list} { var obj = t(); }`. This isn't a list of types, but rather it's a list of delegates, each of which knows how to create an instance of a particular type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need the list to initial an object you could change the list from `List<Type>` to `List<Func<object>>` and use it like this

```
var initList = new List<Func<object>>();
initList.Add(() => string.Empty);
initList.Add(() => new CustomClass());

foreach (var init in initList)
    Console.WriteLine(init());
```

See it in action
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ubvk20

Though I must say that I believe that there would be a better, more ideal, solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `List<Type>` then you have to use `typeof` in order to get the actual `Type` instance for a given class.

```
var typeList = new List<Type>();

typeList.Add(typeof(string));
typeList.Add(typeof(CustomClass));
```

In order to create instances of the `Type`s stored in `typeList`, you can use the [`Activator` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator). Specifically, [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance).

```
foreach (var type in typeList)
{
   var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

However, this still has some problems that you'll have to solve. For example, `inst` in the code above will be a reference to an `object`. You'll have to figure out some way to cast that to whatever `type` is if you want to use it as an instance of that type.

Also, the code above will only work for types which have a constructor which takes no parameters. If a type in `typeList` doesn't have a parameterless constructor, the code above will throw a `MissingMethodException`. This is especially worth mentioning, because in your example you're adding `string` to `typeList`, but [`string` does not have an empty constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor).